# How to bind data in input-tag using Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to bind data in `input_tag` using following code:

```
<label class="item item-input">
<input 
  type="text" 
  placeholder="Title" 
  ng-model="item.Title" minlength="3" 
  ng-blur="validate[0]=true" 
  ng-bind="item.title" />
</label>
```

But when i am using `ng-model` and `ng-value/ng-bind` at the same time. I am unable to get data in input tag. Can you please tell me how to get data in `input_tag`?

Comment: you can show it with out using ng-bind...if you use ng-bing you probably gets an error like untrusted

Comment: without ng-bind also we tried..we have directly passed value to variable in ng-model.but didnt get output

Comment: try to access correctly in model ur giving item.Title and in binding its item.title check it

Comment: Why would you use `ng-bind-html` in an `input` element??? You only need to use `ng-model`

Answer (score 0):

@jahnavi, ng-bind and ng-model are not used at the same time, in input tag we use ng-model, it will bind the input with the controller's object.

Comment: I have used ng-model without ng-bind also but I still couldn't get data. My code in controller:     $rootScope.item.Title = $rootScope.classifiedtitle;

Comment: @jahnavi dont use $rootScope ,it is used to store angular app data, controller variables are used by $scope like:

Comment: <input type="text" placeholder="Title" ng-model="item.Title" />

Comment: $scope.Title= $rootScope.classifiedtitle;

Comment: ignore the above line
<input type="text" placeholder="Title" ng-model="title" /> //variable name are written in camel case
$scope.title= $rootScope.classifiedtitle;

Answer (score 0):

I used a filter to make it trust like below then i didn't get any errors

```
 app .filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function($sce){
        return function(text) {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
        };
    }]);
```

please [check this](http://plnkr.co/edit/FjIoaC04Yo2NkynooHlV?p=preview)  for both ng-bind and ng-model

and [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/mTDQBA54OfBNuO8E3tru?p=preview) for only ng-model with out ng-bind